# How to auto resize JFrame when elements move on next line using FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

While you resize `JFrame` manually via mouse, elements on `JPanel` can go on next line if there is no enough space, same time new element-lines can be removed if `JFrame` is big enough

**Example:**

at this moment there are two lines to fit all `JButton`s
[image]

If I change `JFrame` width via mouse, `JButton`s will drop on next lines:

[image]

the problem is you can't see all `JButton`s, JFrame needs to be resized in height.

How to make `JFrame` auto resize in height to fit all elements according to set width?

Comment: You don't want to use a scroll pane?

Comment: @peeskillet, no, frame should show all elements at once, without scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a very good design. Show me another professional application that works like this? People don't like to see the size of frames jump. The user is usually resizing the frame to fit the app on their desktop and will get frustrated if they fix the width and the height changes. Let the user control the size.

If you want all the buttons to display, then maybe a better solution is to just make the frame non resizable by using:

```
frame.setResizable( false );
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible();
```

Anyway, if you really want to do this then you would probably add a `ComponentListener` to the content pane of the frame. Then in the `componentResized()` method you would invoke pack().

However, this will cause multiple events to be generated every couple of pixels so you may also want to use:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDynamicLayout( false );
```

So that the pack() is only done once when the mouse is released.

Answer (score 0):

```
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(400,200);
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer for the OP?